# Changing the names of multiple files using 'rename'

Tags: linux, perl, rename

I've about 100 files, I'd like to change the letter P to the letter B in all file names. But when using the rename command:

```
rename 's/\P/\Bi/' *.txt
```

I get the following message

```
Empty \P{} in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\P <-- HERE / at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Help Please

Thanks

Comment: Does the Perl [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) command even take a regular expression? How about posting your entire program, or at least enough to know where the _name_ you're renaming is coming from.

Comment: Is `rename` the Perl function, or is this a command called `rename` that's written in Perl?

Comment: @David W.: it's the perl function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes. First you don't need to escape `P` and `B` since they are not special characters. Second if that `i` is meant for case insensitivity then that is a flag and needs to be at the end.

```
rename 's/P/B/i' *.txt
```

This will change the first occurrence of `P` or `p` to `B`. If you want to change all occurrences then use `g` flag which means `global` like this:

```
rename 's/P/B/ig' *.txt
```

**Update based on new requirement:**

From anything complex, it is better off to write your own `perl` script. Here is a quick example using the [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) core module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $dir = '/path/to/your/files/';    # path to your files
opendir my ($dh), $dir;
my @files = grep { /\.txt$/ } readdir $dh;  # create a list of all files

for(@files) {
    my $cnt;
    my $from = $_;
    chomp $from;
    (my $to = $from) =~ s/(P)/++$cnt>=2 && $cnt<=3 ? "B" : $1/gie;
    #print "from:$from   to:$to\n";
    move("$dir$from", "$dir$to") if ($to ne $from);
}
```

We create a temporary variable `$cnt` and with the following condition check if the the character in question is second or third. If it is we replace it with `B` else we retain it as is.

```
++$cnt>=2 && $cnt<=3 ? "B" : $1
```

Comment: Thank. what if I want to change the second or third occurrence only and skip the first?

Comment: I'm getting the following message: 

Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at (eval 1) line 1.
Number found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near 's/P/b/2'
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near '2i'
 (Missing operator before i?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near 's/P/b/2'

Comment: @nytrook I have written a small `perl` script that does that for you. Comment the `move` line and uncomment the `print` line and run the script. It will act as a dry run showing you the what the file name is and what it will renamed to. Once you are satisfied, you can swap the comment statements and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Dont escape letter, also put regexp modifiers after close slash

```
rename 's/P/B/ig' *.txt
```

For more information about regexp see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)